# Would a cherry laurel shrub die if I cut off the top half?

Tags: pruning, shrubs

I have a cherry laurel in my garden that has grown way too big. Would it die if I cut off the top half?[image: The shrub]

Comment: Trees don't die for being butchered. Have a gardener prune hard but unevenly for a softer result:  . v^v . v^v . v^v .

Comment: Depends on the final goal. A low but thick tree for sun cover? A tall but skinny tree? A small shrub? Maximize fruit?

Answer (score 3):

Cherry laurels are tough, vigorous shrubs. Cutting off the top half shouldn't kill it but it still won't be very manageable. If you stool it, ie cut it down to just above (say, a foot above) ground level, it will almost certainly regrow. You can then keep it regularly (I would suggest annually at least) trimmed to the height and shape you want.